# MQL4 - How to set a "today"-datetime to an extern variable in MQL4 script?

Tags: constants, default-value, extern, mql4

I have an MQL4 script ( a script that runs on MetaTrader4 Terminal platform ) and I need to define an **`extern`** variable, named `extractionDate` of type `datetime`, so that the user can change its input value before the script starts.

I tried the conventional way to define the variable before the standard script's function `start()`, but it doesn't work. When I compile I, get the error message

> ['TimeLocal' - constant expected]

that means MQL4 wants a constant value for the variable. But this isn't my goal. I would like to show as default value the "Today" date, when the script starts and not a fixed predefined date value.

Is it possible to do this or not?

```
extern datetime extractionDate = TimeLocal();
int start()
{
   ......
   return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### No, compiler does not allow this directly

Compiler does not allow a way to assign a default value, that is not constant.
It has to know the value, so an attempt to setup / assign an unknown / variable-value as a default one, will yield compilation error.

### Yet, how to solve this?

My approach would be to give user instructions and a choice to setup any **`datetime`**, or setup a value of **`-1`**, which would be translated inside the `OnInit()` event handler code-block:

```
 void   OnInit(){
        ...
        if (  extractionData == -1 ) extractionDate = TimeLocal();
        ...
        }
```